# How to add a condition to a plsql cursor

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written a select query in PLSQL as below.

```
SELECT *
FROM order_tab
WHERE contract = contract_
AND vendor_no  =  vendor_no_
AND category   = category_;
```

I need to add a condition to this code where

- when contract = '*' in order_tab, ignore the condition "contract = contract_"
- when contract in order_tab is some other value, include the where condition "contract = contract_"

Is this possible to achieve using a single select statement.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `OR` condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM   order_tab
WHERE  ( contract = '*' OR contract = contract_ )
AND    vendor_no  =  vendor_no_
AND    category   = category_;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `IN`condition

`SELECT *
  from order_tab
  where contract IN('*','contract_')
  AND vendor_no = vendor_no_
  AND category = category_;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the DECODE function in Oracle

```
SELECT *
FROM order_tab
WHERE contract LIKE DECODE(contract_, ’*’, ’%’, contract_)
AND vendor_no  =  vendor_no_
AND category   = category_;
```

Comment: I'd recommend MT0's answer, simple `OR` expression is always better.